# Add a random number at the end of each line of file

Tags: string, bash, performance, file

I am willing to add a different random number at the end of each line of a file. I have to repeat the process a few times and each file contain about 20k lines and each line contains about 500k characters.

The only solution I came up with so far is

```
file="example.txt"
for lineIndex in $(seq 1 "$(wc -l ${file})")
do
    lineContent=$(sed "${lineIndex}q;d" ${file})
    echo "${lineContent} $RANDOM" >> tmp.txt
done
mv tmp.txt ${file}
```

Is there a faster solution?

Comment: `cat ${file} | wc -l` is Useless Use Of Cat.  Just `wc -l ${file}`.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of code review is always good to take! Post edited.

Comment: Reading a file line by line: [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk:

```
awk '{ print $0, int(32768 * rand()) }' "$file" > tmp && \
    mv tmp "$file"
```

Comment: @Remi.b: Make sure to use `srand` or the random numbers will be the same each time, by the way

Answer (score 5):

You can do it much simpler, and without opening and closing the input and output files and spawning new processes on every line, like this:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line $RANDOM"
done < "$file" > tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} {print $0, int(rand() * 10^5+1)}' file
```

If you have gnu awk then you can use `inplace` saving of file:

```
awk -i inplace -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} {print $0, int(rand() * 10^5+1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script could be rewritten as:

```
file="example.txt"
cat ${file} | while read line; do
    echo "${line} $RANDOM"
done > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt ${file}
```